# Drools, if one of multiple values not equals null then assign this values to variable

Tags: java, drools

Drools, if one of multiple values not equals null then assign this values to variable

how i can resolve this logic properly accodting to drools syntax ??

```
when
  Man ($vallet : man.vallet != null || man.getAttribute("vallet") != null)
then
  ...
```

*only one wont equal null*

Comment: Use a ternary operator

Comment: This isn't possible. (The term "assign" is wrong: you *bind* a variable to a field or an object.) Why don't you resolve this in a getter getVallet inside class Man? (Showing the class definition of Man might help to provide another workaround.)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your rule to bind either the value of `vallet` or `getAttribute("vallet")` based on which one is not null:

`rule
when
    Man( $vallet : vallet != null ) or Man( $vallet : getAttribute("vallet") != null )
then
...`